# How to handle .Net XML serialization exception?

Tags: .net, web-services

I am working on a project that utilizes .Net API (several .Net DLLs) provided by the customer. I have built an application based on this API. Application works as expected on my machines. But when I tried deploying it on client’s machine it fails with a rather generic exception. I tried googling for this exception but nothing conclusive could be found.

To give a rough idea about this API, it wraps a web service consumer and therefore requires marshaling of method parameters into XML (no source code available for this). Following is the stack trace for the exception:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero
>   length.    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterStreamInformation.Write5_StreamInformation(Object
>   o)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Loader.StringSerializer`1.Serialize(TSerializable
>   instance)    **at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Loader.LoaderClient.BeginExecuteBinary(AsyncCallback
>   endLoadCallback, AsyncCallback startSendingDataCallback, Object state)**
>   *> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Loader.AABinLoaderClient.CofingDoLoad(String[]
>   configVals)*

frame in Italic represents our application while Frame in bold represents the client's API
If anyone has encountered this exception in the past and know any workaround please do let me know.

Comment: Is this using custom xml serialization or is the serialization generated for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this kind of error when trying to parse XML. The most common place I have seen the "String cannot have zero length" error is when it is trying to find a particular place within a string. Do you know if this API is using the XML namespace?

Without seeing any code it is difficult to provide any detailed analysis of your problem.

Comment: i have updated the whole stacktrace can you have a look at it and comment.

Comment: Its hard to try a workaround if the API is serializing the data for you. Are you providing the data to be serialized?

Comment: Are you adding any illegal characters in the data you are passing to the API? Is it sending data to an SQL database?

Comment: Yes we are passing illegal characters is this can be a reason??? We are also sending the data to database.

Comment: Have you been able to add data to your database before using the type of data you are trying to insert using the API? I know that some databases are fussy about what you try and put into them.